# Check for Admin user without using JEDI

Tags: delphi

An answer to a [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019286/checking-for-administrator-user-login-in-non-english-installations-of-windows) offered a check for membership of the administrators group which works on Vista and above, unlike the (so I learn) deprecated method I have been using up to now. But I don't really want to install the whole JEDI API just to get the definitions of a few function headers and constants which are absent from the Delphi VCL, and the JEDI API download doesn't seem to support XE yet. Even if XE turns out to be supported in the lastest SVN files, an 11MB install still seems like overkill just to do this task. Can anyone suggest a source for a simple, tested standalone Delphi routine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Be aware that you can include the JwaXXX.pas files separately from JEDI API. The file contains the whole package with all sources which definitely aren't included in your EXE but on your hard drive (I hope you still have enough space for it)

And yes, XE is supported! Nothing has changed here. Why should there be a separate packages for XE? Just use Subversion to update and fix some problems (which are unrelated to XE).

JEDI API is not necessary too be installed. However, you need to setup the path so Delphi can find the source files. If don't need JEDI WSCL than you don't need to include them or even remove the files from disk.

Of course, you can use this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546643/how-do-i-check-if-my-program-is-ran-by-user-as-administrator-vista-win7-c/4051152#4051152) and convert it yourself. In this way you have 100% control over it.

Comment: +1: The single units are a direct conversion of Windows SDK header files so your exe won't get much bigger by using them!

Comment: Thanks, I now have two good solutions!  My reluctance to install more than I need stems from a resolution to avoid IDE bloat as I move from 2010 to XE. I try to do this every second or third Delphi release to get rid of the fluff that otherwise accumulates.  None of this reflects on your excellent work on JWA!